# Creating a pandas column that performs a calculation on another column, but changes the variable in the calculation based on a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently a dataframe that contains a column called `load`, and I want to create a column called `calculated load`, that uses a simple formula on the column load, and a variable. However, I want the calculation to change the variable it uses when it sees the value 1 in a column called `postition`, and uses that formula until it sees -1 in position, when the values start to rise again. Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

s_falling = -4
s_rising = 2
x = 2

df = pd.DataFrame({"load": [1,2,4,6,2,4,7,4,8,3,4,7,3,3,6,4,7,4,3,2],
                   "position": [0,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.7,1,0.7,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.2,0,-0.5,-0.8,-1,-0.8,-0.9,-0.7,-0.6]})

df['calculated load'] = df['load'] + x * s_rising

print(df['calculated load'])

0      5
1      6
2      8
3     10
4      6
5      8
6     11
7      8
8     12
9      7
10     8
11    11
12     7
13     7
14    10
15     8
16    11
17     8
18     7
19     6
```

This works up to the position after 1, when the values start falling, I want to use this formula that swaps `s_rising` for `s_falling`, and continues to use this new variable with the formula iterating over the column, and then reverts back to the original formula using the variable `s_rising` from the position after -1 is seen again:

```
df['calculated load'] = df['load'] + x *s_falling
```

The formula doesn't change, merely the variable being used within it.

I can't just check if the value after is less than or more than the previous value, as the values in position don't rise and fall perfectly. Ideally, this would be my desired output:

```
print(df['calculated load'])

0      5
1      6
2      8
3     10
4      6
5      8
6      3
7      0
8      4
9     -1
10     0
11     3
12    -1
13    -1
14     2
15     0
16    11
17     8
18     7
19     8
```

EDIT: Some very kind people have offered solutions, and I have realised that my question (designed to produce a small, reproducible example) was slightly off the mark. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Is it normal that position goes from 0.5 then 0.8 and then decrease to 0.7?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't perfectly rise and fall, it might slightly rise or fall against the pattern of values. However, 1 and -1 will always be seen.

Comment: I see, initially I wanted to use the diff() method to compute the difference between two consecutives "position" rows and say if this difference is positive it's increasing else it's decreasing. But the function isn't monotic. I'm gonna try something but it may not be the most efficient way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this & let me know if it's work.

```
x = 2

df = pd.DataFrame({"load": [1,2,4,6,2,4,7,4,8,3,4,7,3,3,6,4,7,4,3,2],
                    "position": [0,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.7,1,0.7,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.2,0,-0.5,-0.8,-1,-0.8,-0.9,-0.7,-0.6]})




for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df[df['position']==1.0].index[0]<=i<df[df['position']==-1.0].index[0]:
        
        df.loc[i, 'calculated load'] = df.loc[i, 'load'] - x
        
    else:
        
        df.loc[i, 'calculated load'] = df.loc[i, 'load'] + x
    
        
print(df)

load  position  calculated load
0      1       0.0              3.0
1      2       0.2              4.0
2      4       0.5              6.0
3      6       0.8              8.0
4      2       0.7              4.0
5      4       1.0              2.0
6      7       0.7              5.0
7      4       0.6              2.0
8      8       0.7              6.0
9      3       0.8              1.0
10     4       0.4              2.0
11     7       0.2              5.0
12     3       0.0              1.0
13     3      -0.5              1.0
14     6      -0.8              4.0
15     4      -1.0              6.0
16     7      -0.8              9.0
17     4      -0.9              6.0
18     3      -0.7              5.0
19     2      -0.6              4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code is working, but it's not efficient because of `itterrows()`. If someone find a way to vectorize it you can comment my answer.

```
import pandas as pd

x = 2

df = pd.DataFrame({"load": [1,2,4,6,2,4,7,4,8,3,4,7,3,3,6,4,7,4,3,2],
                   "position": [0,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.7,1,0.7,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.2,0,-0.5,-0.8,-1,-0.8,-0.9,-0.7,-0.6]})

increasing = True
list_increasing = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if increasing and row.position == 1:
        increasing = False
    elif not increasing and row.position == -1:
        increasing = True
    list_increasing.append(increasing)
    
df['increasing'] = list_increasing

def calculated_load(row):
    if row.increasing:
        return row.load + x
    else:
        return row.load - x

df['cal load'] = df.apply(calculated_load, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Someone else has provided a vectorized solution however, but I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: I have realised that my initial question was a bit off the mark - I  have edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Without loop, you can use:

```
x1 = df['position'].eq(1).mul(-x).shift(fill_value=0)
x2 = df['position'].eq(-1).mul(x)
xm = (p1|p2).replace(0, np.nan).ffill().fillna(x).astype(int)

df['calculated load'] = df['load'] + xm
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    load  position  calculated load
0      1       0.0                3
1      2       0.2                4
2      4       0.5                6
3      6       0.8                8
4      2       0.7                4
5      4       1.0                6
6      7       0.7                5
7      4       0.6                2
8      8       0.7                6
9      3       0.8                1
10     4       0.4                2
11     7       0.2                5
12     3       0.0                1
13     3      -0.5                1
14     6      -0.8                4
15     4      -1.0                6
16     7      -0.8                9
17     4      -0.9                6
18     3      -0.7                5
19     2      -0.6                4
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, this works great! I assume you meant `(p1|p2)` to be `(x1|x2)` however?

Comment: I have realised that your solution works for just one variable, 'x'. I used x to provide a simple reproducible example, but I've realised it's not what I'm looking for. I will update the question to reflect this